# Angular JS Repeating through 2 Arrays In Unordered List

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I got this html:

```
 <ul class="demo-list-three mdl-list">
    <li class="mdl-list__item mdl-list__item--three-line" ng-repeat="p in projects">
        <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
            <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar">person</i>
            <span>{{p}}</span>
            <span class="mdl-list__item-text-body">
                {{descriptions[0]}}
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-content">
            <a class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action" href="#"><i class="material-icons">star</i></a>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Projects and descriptions are Arrays in my Controller. Now I'm getting for each item in my Project Array a listitem, but how can I iterate the description as well?

Like in the first Iteration:

```
<span>{{descriptions[0]}}</span>
```

And in the next Iteration for the next p in Projects:

```
<span>{{descriptions[1]}}</span>
```

Thanks in regard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [track by](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) in ng-repeat

```
<ul class="demo-list-three mdl-list">
    <li class="mdl-list__item mdl-list__item--three-line" ng-repeat="p in projects track by $index">
        <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
            <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar">person</i>
            <span>{{p}}</span>
            <span class="mdl-list__item-text-body">
                {{descriptions[$index]}}
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-content">
            <a class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action" href="#"><i class="material-icons">star</i></a>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You were to fast, you have to wait for 5 minutes ;)